# Apex class code is getting highlighted when I tried to check code coverage

Tags: salesforce, apex

[image]

Test class :

```
@isTest
public class PriceName_PriceList_test {
    
    @istest static void PriceName_PriceListMethod(){
                
        PriceName_PriceList priceObj = new PriceName_PriceList();
        Product_Line_Item__c prl = New Product_Line_Item__c();
        prl = [SELECT Product_Name__r.name, List_Price__c FROM Product_Line_Item__c];
                
         prl.Product_Name__r.name = 'testproduct';
         prl.List_Price__c = 123;
         
             
         insert  prl;
         PriceObj.getdetails();
             }
    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't pass the Id to the class. So with a null the query will return 0. But it's interesting, I'd expect you to at least get coverage for line 6...

Change your code to this and run again

```
insert  prl;
PriceObj.drId = prl.Id;
PriceObj.getdetails();
```

Or make the function accept an Id parameter and call `PriceObj.getdetails(prl.Id)`, no idea what's your use case